# Set value to object in property

Tags: javascript, object

In JavaScript object, we can

```
var myobj = {
    x: 0,
    y: {
        n: 6
    }
};
myobj['x'] = 6; // myobj.x will be 6
```

Can I do something like this with a function?—

```
myobj['y.n'] = 6;
```

I don't want use `myobj.y.n`.

Comment: *Why* do you not want to use `myobj.y.n` ?

Comment: Probably because it's dynamic

Comment: @ThiefMaster But he's still referring to it statically, so it can't be *that* dynamic.

Comment: Is `myobj['y']['n']` not an option?

Comment: I don't know the name of variable, it will be added by the user

Comment: @DavidThomas, I can do that if I know variable name??

Comment: But even so, the principle remains precisely the same, it just requires adding some string functions to *find* and `split()` the string from which the values/names are coming.

Comment: @Quentin, The objectif is not recieve or return the value, the objectif is set a value

Comment: @WaelAmineBoutglay — The principle is the same. You need to access the property in either case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no built-in way to resolve this kind of object path. However, there are quite a few small libraries available for this such as [goodwin](https://github.com/logicalparadox/goodwin).

Or you could implement it on your own. It's not really hard. Simply split the path string at `.` and then walk through the objects.